# Suggestion: Use rel="canonical" to improve Stack Overflow's Google results

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, google, seo

Google [now supports](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) `<link rel="canonical">`, which allow a page to point to the canonical version of itself.  This would help to fix a problem with Stack Overflow's Google search results, in that questions appear multiple times for no good reason.

For example, the result page for:

- "How to find header dependencies for large scale projects on linux"

shows the question three times under different URLs, starting with the canonical one but then also including the superfluous:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80923?sort=newest
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80923?sort=oldest

If each page had in its `<head>` section a `<link rel="canonical">` pointing to the canonical page, that shouldn't happen any more.

(Meta meta: Try as I might I can't get links to work. Apologies for the lack of links in this question.)

Comment: ...on the other hand, having three links on the first page of search results crowds out two other links from the front page of Google.  Muahahahahaha! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We already do this.

```
<div id="question-header">
    <h2>
    <a href="/questions/6193/suggestion-use-relcanonical-to-improve-stack-overflows-google-results" 
        class="question-hyperlink" rel="canonical">
    Suggestion: Use rel=&rdquo;canonical&rdquo; to improve Stack Overflow&rsquo;s Google results
    </a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Notice "rel canonical".

**edit**: oh, I see. I think I misunderstood what Google wanted here (eg, one link in header versus a "nofollow" style attrib that goes on the *all the hyperlinks* you want to make canonical). Making the change.

Comment: This answer alone is a bit confusing. May be worth mentioning the actual fix is removing the rel='canonical' from the <a href> and using it as proposed on the question like <link rel='canonical'>.

Answer (score 3):

Huh, I thought they did already, but it looks like they're only putting `rel="canonical"` in links to other pages on the site.

Comment: Is that even meaningful?  I guess not, judging by Jeff's edit on his own post.

Answer (score -2):

IMO, `rel="canonical"` is just a work-around. A perfect solution to resolve the problem would be to hide parameters like `sort=newest` in POST request.

A drawback is a lack of permalink. But does anyone share the links like [active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/suggestion-use-rel-canonical-to-improve-stack-overflows-google-results?answertab=active#tab-top), [oldest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/suggestion-use-rel-canonical-to-improve-stack-overflows-google-results?answertab=oldest#tab-top) or [votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/suggestion-use-rel-canonical-to-improve-stack-overflows-google-results?answertab=votes#tab-top)? I don't think so - there is already a way to share a question or a single answer and this is enough.

After the change, URLs with  any `?queryParams` should `301 Permanent Redirect` to their canonical version without any query string parameters. This will make Google forget the old URLs almost immediately.

Currently, 3 years after `link[rel=canonical]` was implemented, Google knows about these URLs. `robots.txt` correctly say not to index them but still - [Google keeps na eye on it](https://www.google.pl/search?q=How+to+find+header+dependencies+for+large+scale+projects+on+linux+answertab) and will include them in the search results if needed. The description will just be empty.

The most clean approach is to provide a permalink to what you want shared by people and indexed by robots, and a dynamic link to what you don't want to.

Comment: We share those links all the time.