# How often does Google index SO content?

Tags: discussion, google, indexing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [SEO in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stackoverflow)
>   [How frequently are new questions indexed by search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/how-frequently-are-new-questions-indexed-by-search-engines)

In the past, I believe I've noticed that SO questions appear on Google within about half an hour.

However, I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134391/create-an-interactive-logon-session/2179747#2179747) 5 hours ago and Google [still gives no results](http://www.google.com/search?q=shgina.dll+ShellLocalMachine+%2BInitiateInteractiveLogon).

Are frequent updates only for questions?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/how-does-stackoverflow-do-so-very-well-on-google or the dupe-father: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stackoverflow

Comment: @random: Those aren't duplicates.  I saw those questions when writing this one.  They don't even mention the indexing frequency.

Comment: How about this one then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/how-frequently-are-new-questions-indexed-by-search-engines

Comment: Then this would be more about asking Google since SO doesn't control Google.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a good - but duplicate - question. Duplicates should get closed, not downvoted. Now I gave him a sympathy upvote, which I wouldn't have done if he wasn't downvoted, and so he got 6 free rep. =p

Comment: @Koper Do not do sympathy upvotes, ever, under any circumstances, for any reason at all.

Comment: @Koper Pity upvotes basically destroy the system. If someone posts a bad question, getting a single upvote will nullify 5 downvotes that say the question does not deserve its place.

Comment: @Koper: FYI: When I am elected moderator I will suspend you pity upvoting. Pity upvoting is a recognized problem with Stack Overflow and is considered harmful. You are admitting to willfully harming Stack Overflow and therefore should not continue doing so unpunished.

Comment: When you pity upvote you tell everyone that you don't read what you're voting on. @kop

Comment: @koper I don't downvote duplicates - I vote to close them. On meta I don't have the rep to do this, so I leave them alone.

Answer (score 3):

Google indexes websites when it feels good and ready.

Answer (score 0):

It's finally been indexed, 6 hours later.

Comment: So the answer is 6 hours later?

Comment: @Arjan: What do you mean?

Comment: The Google search result says `12 hours ago`, whereas the answer says `18 hours ago`.  Thus, 6 hours later.

Comment: *finally*? 6 hours from conception to index is pretty quick. If you're not impressed by that then....wow. I'm sure there's a timing element to this, too. I've seen search results point back to questions I asked less than an hour ago...

Comment: What, do you want Google to crawl **all** over stalkoverflow (I actually wrote that accidentally!) again and again every few minutes, slowing down StackOverflow to a crawl itself? (Google has more resources than SO, so I bet they could take it down... Yes! Google must turn evil!)