# How do Stack Overflow questions appear on Google just after posting?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stackoverflow)

It seems like Stack Overflow enjoys some privileges at Google. Whenever I ask a question and then do a search on Google (to check if I may have missed something or can the find the answer myself, now that I've asked the question...you know that, right? You can't find the freaking answer for *days*, but the moment you ask it on the Internet the answer suddenly flies to you!) my answer appears in the search.

How is Stack Exchange doing that? Do you guys have some special privilege or agreement with Google, so that they're checking your sites in real-time? Or is this just happening because Stack Overflow is so big and awesome?

Comment: Why does it now say "migrated 5 mins ago"?

Comment: mmyers: Because migration time was replace with closing time. I think an entry to this issue already exists, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 14):

([Serious answer appears elsewhere.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33672/how-do-stackoverflow-questions-appear-on-google-just-after-posting/33675#33675))

Here's the rough steps involved in a question appearing:

1. User hits "Post Your Question"

   - I intercept the request, and read the question.
   - I prepare an answer.
   - I change all existing information on the internet to make it clear that my answer is the one and only True Answer to the question.
   - I allow the original request to reach the SO web server, and wait for it to be processed.
   - I post my answer to the question, leaving a few nanoseconds between the question becoming visible and my answer appearing. After all, I wouldn't want to be unfair to other users.
   - **I update the Google index to include the question.**
   - I use subliminal signals (typically via slight fluctuations in power supplies) to nudge SO users towards my answer, gently drawing their cursors to the upvote button.

As you can see, step 7 is the one relevant to your question. I just thought you'd want a bit of context.

Comment: -1 - no freehand circles, waffles, ponies, or M. ??? N. Profit!

Comment: Hey, what's with all the Jon Skeet love? It's like you're... oh, wait.

Comment: What about the 5 sockpuppet accounts?! You missed that bit

Answer (score 12):

Google knows that Stack Overflow's content is updated regularly, so it polls the sitemap more often than it would for a site which only changes once a month. As far as I'm aware, this is entirely automatic (I'd be shocked if it were manual) - the crawler is just self-tuning to make search results as "fresh" as possible without trying to hit every web site in the world every 20 seconds.

(Disclaimer: I work for Google, but not on the search team. I'm not that smart :)

Comment: Why do you need to be smart**er** to work on the search team than on another team? You would need to be an expert in that particular area, obviously, but as long as you are not stupid I doubt intelligence plays a big role.

Comment: There is also a discussion on the podcasts about this site's extensive sitemap tweaking to tell the Googlebot what has changed.

Comment: @Koper: For one thing: if you screw something up in search and it somehow gets through QA, you're going to make a *lot* of people cross... and cost the company a *lot* of money. I suspect there's also more algorithmic understanding necessary for search than for most other products. Like all generalisations, there are exceptions of course.

Comment: @Koper - perhaps not smarter but you do have to be able to click and cut and paste very quickly to index all the sites on the net.

Comment: @Jon Shouldn't screwups that get through QA be QA's fault? :-)

Comment: You don't have to be smart to work on a search team. There are dozens of morons on the Bing team. (I kid I kid!)

Comment: @ceejayoz: bwahahaha. good one.

Answer (score 7):

It's all part of the magic of...

http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/4236/theinternetjazzhands.gif

Answer (score 0):

It's Google's new real-time search initiative, in which they're indexing certain sites as close to real-time as they can.

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/relevance-meets-real-time-web.html

> First, we're introducing new features
>   that bring your search results to life
>   with a dynamic stream of real-time
>   content from across the web. Now,
>   immediately after conducting a search,
>   you can see live updates from people
>   on popular sites like Twitter and
>   FriendFeed, as well as headlines from
>   news and blog posts published just
>   seconds before. When they are
>   relevant, we'll rank these latest
>   results to show the freshest
>   information right on the search
>   results page.

Comment: I don't believe this affects Stack Overflow though - in particular, Google results for Stack Overflow have been very quick for months, well before this went live.

Comment: It's been known for some time that Google "optimizes" its bot activity by indexing frequently updated sites more often, and indexing infrequently updated sites less often.

Comment: SO isn't a real-time source like Twitter, FriendFeed, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz - It may not be categorized as such by google, but it's real time in terms of a constant feed of new posts and information.