# Posts in Stack Overflow instantly searchable?

Tags: discussion, seo, indexing, search-engine, stack-overflow

Just a random question, all the questions I have created in Stack Overflow instantly searchable the moment I publish it.

How is it possible? I thought you will need to wait for google to crawl the site first which usually takes around 2 weeks ?

Comment: Should this question be migrated to [webmaster.se] instead?

Comment: @Alvin no, it's asking about Stack Overflow not about websites in general and Meta is the place to discuss anything related to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But the answer, as you can see, is not only related to StackOverflow site(s).

Answer (score 6):

Google groups pages by how often they update, and crawls the frequently changing ones more often. That's why the indexes to news sites are always fresh too.

Comment: Not to mention that SE has some of the best SEO around to help with that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stack-overflow