# How do I search on Google to avoid duplicate Meta questions

Tags: support, search

I know how to search on [Google](http://google.com.ng) to avoid duplicating Stack Overflow posts. All I need to do is type the question followed by a tag.

E.g [How to update the GUI from another thread [c#]](https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=How%20to%20update%20the%20GUI%20from%20another%20thread%20%5Bc#%5D)

It gives me the results for such questions on Stack Overflow and other sites.

Now how do I do the same for Meta?

Comment: Append `site:meta.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Why the down vote. I just asked a question??????

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there is a search box at the top right, you really don't need to be using google for this.

Comment: @Dave Ha! search box. The duplicate box on ask a new question is pretty good though

Comment: I would add to Dave's comment though (also not as a downvoter) this is really a question about how to use google rather than anything about stack exchange

Comment: @RichardTingle frankly I agree with you, but I didn't downvote because it is less work to find duplicates when someone learns proper searching to avoid dups.

Comment: lazy people always downvoting!

Comment: @DaveChen there is a good reason to use SE search  AND google.... google searching is a lot more flexible.  The power of SE search is in the operators, but if you just have keywords, google is actually better

Comment: @Jason, how is downvoting lazy? You have locate the down arrow and click on it, you know.

Comment: Luckily you don't have to read the question @FrédéricHamidi. Otherwise I wouldn't downvote a thing any more. ;)

Comment: @Bart, what is that reading thing you're talking about?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: its just a click!  this question has nothing to downvote, OP wants to avoid asking duplicate question, the question is also useful for other readers. I am still don't understand downvoters disagree with what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Appending a tag will not guarantee a result from Stack Overflow, but a lot of that is due to our fantastic SEO.  However since Stack Overflow tends to be ranked very highly you are more likely to get a SO post, but, the 5th highest post in the search you linked is not from Stack Overflow, so obviously it is not "site specific"

The proper way to use google to search a specific site is to use the `site` operator, followed by the URL (e.g. `site:meta.stackoverflow.com`)

In fact, this question is already #4 on Google for site a specific search:

Google search string: `google duplicate search site:meta.stackoverflow.com` (I tried to link the search link itself, but apparently it is not permitted)

This works on any site.  It is especially helpful in finding cross-site dups by using a wild card (`site:*.stackexchange.com`) but doesn't quite work well for sites that have domains that are not .stackexchange.com (the trilogy + MSO)

And [Jason OOO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199679/182513) provides some good advanced operators for effective google searching.

Comment: Out of curiosiy, how does "our fantastic SEO" work, apart from just having very on-topic content?

Comment: @KerrekSB unfortunately I don't know.  All I know is questions get indexed within minutes so Google thinks very highly of us.

Comment: @Kerrek, our awesome answers make our fantastic SEO work. (Well, that, and word of mouth.) You should know, as you're one of our primary providers ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB here's an early question on the SEO: [SEO in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14056/182513)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@psubsee2003's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199675/234196), you can find other useful operators here: [Google Search Operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html), and this question: [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)
lets just use one example:

if you want to find related question using question title, you can use:

```
site:meta.stackoverflow.com intitle:my keyword
```

Google searches for `my keyword` or `my` or `keyword` within title of pages (Which is question title), and applies first condition only in `meta.stackoverflow.com`, in this example you can enclose the `my keyword` with quotes such as `"my keyword"` so that google uses both words together in the search.