# Does Stack Exchange guide Google to the biggest user profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, network-profile

EDIT:

Several people suggested to me to look at *[SEO in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stack-overflow)*, however this would suggest the **opposite** of what is happening. The content on (and linked from) my Stack Overflow profile is definitely richer than on my other profile pages, yet the Stack Overflow page is listed much lower than others.

Also my Stack Overflow profile has more inbound links, so again it should be ranked higher normally.

---

Over the time I have ended up with quite a few profiles across Stack Exchange sites. By far the largest (and still most active) is my Stack Overflow profile, there are a few medium size ones and some others are quite inactive/small.

Recently I googled my own name (same as my username), and I saw several profiles of different Stack Exchange sites, but I actually had to go to the second page to reach Stack Overflow.

Currently the first page shows [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) which I also used recently, and also [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour), both of which I have not touched in ages.

I understand I could probably fix this with some [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) tricks (like linking to my Stack Overflow profile from my other ones), but I was still wondering the following:

## Does Stack Exchange do anything 'smart' to help google put the most active profiles on top? -- And if so, why is my top profile not on top?

And of course, if I need to configure something for this, how would that work?

Side note: I always synchronise my description across all profiles so I don't think that caused the situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SEO in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stack-overflow) Not specifically about user profiles, but I think the same principles apply.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has so many downvotes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually the answers to that question describe the opposite of what I am seeing. Have updated the question to emphasise the discrepancy. Please consider withdrawing the close vote.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Perhaps my question was too sublte, I also bolded my observation that I actually see my rich profile NOT being on top.

Comment: interesting question; I'm not *aware* of doing anything special here, but that doesn't mean that we don't... (I'm ignorant of a great many things)

Comment: Too many inbound links (whether you control them or not) may be seen as a sort of [link farming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_farm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a valid question, but I doubt Stack Exchange can answer it. The answer is likely only for Google to tell; we don't know how their search algorithm works.

I couldn't spot anything different in different profiles based on reputation or activity.

I do agree some strange things are happening, but I doubt it's due to profiles being "bigger" than others.

Comment: I guess if nobody here knows anything being done in this area, the answer is in fact given (no, SE does not guide google proactively to relevant profiles). -- Interesting observation: Bing and Yandex actually put my SO profile on top, while Google and Baidu don't. I suspect they may order it by date crawled or something intangible.

Comment: @Dennis yeah, that's probably true.