# Why do Stack Exchange URLs expand to include an additional fragment to the route?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, navigation

A Stack Exchange question URL has the form:

```
stackexchangesitename.com/questions/question-id
```

A Stack Exchange user profile URL also has a similar form:

```
stackexchangesitename.com/users/user-id
```

However, when a page is visited using a URL of the above form, usually an additional verbose segment is appended to the URL. For instance, if I visit:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1
```

The URL changes to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood
```

Similarly, if I navigate to this question:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204
```

The URL changes to:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast
```

That's the entire title in [kebab-case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820138/11455105)!

What exactly is the purpose of this verbose suffix that gets added to these URL routes? What do these additional fragments represent?

Comment: I can speculate a bit: For Google SEO it is important to have one url for the same content, aka the canonical url. Google penalizes your ranking if you have many urls for the same stuff. SE want to have something recognizable from the title in the url, the so called title slug. Given the Google requirement and the UX requirement for having a somewhat readable url in the address bar all shortcut urls (/q/{id}, /a/{id}, /questions/{id}) redirect first with a 302/301 response to the canonical long form.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me @rene

Comment: @Luuklag If it's more than speculation, yes. Is it?

Comment: @Luuklag it could well be that Jeff comes by and says: *because that was the default in ASP.NET MVC in 2008 and I couldn't find the frigging config switch to turn it off*

Comment: @rene But the slugs *break* canonicity of the URL. Whenever the title of the question changes, the “canonical” URL changes.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek yeah, you're probably right. I'm going off posts like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42105/158100 but I haven't looked at a recent sitemap.xml so don't know if they still consider the url + slug as canonical.

Comment: Related: *[Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237/documentation-for-stack-exchange-engine-urls/332251#332251)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was asked a while ago on Stack Overflow:  [Why do some websites add slugs to the end of URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls) (although it's not specific to SE, it seems to apply here as well).  From the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428/13138080) there:

> The slugs make the URL more user-friendly and you know what to expect when you click a link. Search engines such as Google rank the pages higher if the searchword is in the URL.

A better explanation is also given [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls#comment2436785_47427).

Comment: This is a really solid answer; on a only loosely related note, the *lack* of this is one of my biggest pet peeves with the URLs of sites like YouTube, which give zero indication of page content in their URLs. I like being able to hover over links on Stack and have a minor idea of where I'm headed.

Comment: @zcoop98 *immediately proceeds to replace [full link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls) with [a shorter link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/)*