# Set canonical URL for questions

Tags: bug, seo

I googled an error message in quotes and got two results, both from Ask Ubuntu. Upon closer inspection, they were just the two different URL styles for the same question. I'd like to suggest that SE choose one as the canonical URL for SEO purposes.

[(The Google search that led me to ask this)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22proxyjump%22+%22channel+0%3A+open+failed%3A+administratively+prohibited%3A+open+failed%22+%22stdio+forwarding+failed%22&oq=%22proxyjump%22+%22channel+0%3A+open+failed%3A+administratively+prohibited%3A+open+failed%22+%22stdio+forwarding+failed%22)

Comment: The first listed is actually a direct link to an answer, rather than the question.

Comment: Sure that isn't more a google problem, rather than SE's?

Comment: @ale It seems you're right, but why doesn't it jump to the answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, it's up to the site to set a canonical URL when multiple URLs point to the same page. How would Google determine that with absolute certainty (which it would need to do)?

Comment: Related: [Improper use of rel=canonical is hurting search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130749/21960)

Comment: @ale: Only tangentially related, though. Also, I just checked, and it seems as if that bug may have been quietly fixed at some point, despite being marked as [meta-tag:status-declined].