# Suggestion: rel=“canonical” should point to the migrated question when it is migrated

Tags: feature-request, search, google, seo

As suggested, [rel=“canonical” was added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6193) to improve SO results in Google.

It would be even better for this canonical link to directly point to the migrated destination if it is migrated. That way all the incoming links will also benefit the real question, not the closed one.

For example, the rel on SO's question [3052805](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052805) points to [itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052805/what-does-represent-while-giving-path) instead of pointing directly to the question [153165 of SU](https://superuser.com/questions/153165/what-does-represent-while-giving-path) .