# The same question appears twice in a Google search

Tags: bug, google

Doing a Google search for "db migrate reset" gave two hits from the same question with only mildly different URLs:

- [Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload)
- [Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload/36469145)

[image: Screenshot of Google search]

Is it possible for Stack Exchange to inform Google that the two URLs refer to the same question, and therefore shouldn't appear twice?

Similar question, but from 2009 and marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [Suggestion: Use rel="canonical" to improve Stack Overflow's Google results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/suggestion-use-rel-canonical-to-improve-stack-overflows-google-results)

Comment: One of those links is to the question and the other is to an answer on that question. Confusing, but not strictly speaking *wrong* IMO. FWIW, I only see the question once in my search results with the same terms: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaFXE.png